# rails-rspec uniqueness validation using accepts_nested_attributes_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, validation, rspec, unique

**My models relationship like**

```
class Cart < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :cart_items, :inverse_of => :cart, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :cart_items, :allow_destroy => :true, :reject_if => proc { |attrs| attrs.all? { |k, v| v.blank? } }
  validates_associated :cart_items
  validates :cart_name, :presence => {:message => "Must be filled" }
end

class CartItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :cart, :inverse_of => :cart_items
  validates :cart_item_no, :presence => {:message => "Must be filled"}, :uniqueness => {:message => "Already exists" }
end
```

**factories.rb**

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :cart do
    cart_name "sample"
    factory :cart_with_cart_items do
      after(:build) {|cart|
        2.times { cart.cart_items.build(attributes_for(:cart_item)) }
      }
      after(:create) {|cart|
        cart.cart_items.each {|cart_item| cart_item.save! }
      }
    end
  end

  factory :cart_item  do
    cart_item_no 1
    cart
  end
end
```

Below test case always fails

```
it "should not be valid with same cart_id" do
  cart = FactoryGirl.build(:cart_with_cart_items)
  cart.should_not be_valid
end
```

then I exploring in console, validation always returning true with same *cart_item_no* twice in **cart_items** by the example of below code.

```
cart = Cart.new(:cart_name => "yyy")
  => #<Cart id: nil, cart_name: "yyy">
2.times { cart.cart_items.build(:cart_item_no => 1000) }
  => 2
cart.cart_items 
  => [#<CartItem id: nil, cart_item_no: 1000>, #<CartItem id: nil, cart_item_no: 1000>]
cart.valid?
  => true
cart.save!
  => true
```

Is this rails problem?

how to solve test case?

Answer (score 0):

Uniqness validation checks against the database only. In your case, you have two `cart_items` that conflict with each other but not with any record in the database, so individually, both are valid, which is why your validations passes.

You could add a custom validation in your `Cart` class (not tested):

```
validates :unique_cart_items

def unique_cart_items
  unless cart_items.collect(&:cart_item_no).uniq.size < cart_items.size
    # set some error attribute here
  end
end
```

This compares the number of unique `cart_item_no` values to the number of `cart_items`. If they are not the same, there's a duplicate `cart_item_no`.

Comment: If I comment `accepts_nested_attributes_for` in cart model, working as  expected i.e only one *cart_items* record is saved in database table and another object is return with errors.